# How can I convert Record to Row at type Level?

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

I have a record, I want to pass a partial record to a function which will update the current record.

```
type Person = {name :: String, age :: Int }

updatePerson :: forall fullRec partialRec.
              Union fullRec partialRec fullRec 
            => Record fullRec 
            -> Record partialRec
            -> Record fullRec
updatePerson a b = ....
```

I can use `merge` and `union` in purescript-record, but my use case is different. I will call a foreign function with that argument which will update the global `Person` object which in, let's say, in the window object... so the function will only receive the partial record to be updated.

I want to do something like

```
foreign import updatePersonInWindow :: forall a. {|a} -> Effect Unit
updatePerson' :: forall fullRec partialRec.
              Union Person partialRec Person 
            => Record partialRec
            -> Effect Unit
updatePerson' rec = updatePersonInWindow rec
```

`The above one will fail, because` Person `is a Type, not of Row Kind...`

Currently i'm calling directly calling the foreign function, so one can pass any field to it, even though it's not inside the `Person` Record. How can I do it in type safe way?

PS: I could do

`Union (name :: String, age :: Int) partialRec (name :: String, age :: Int)`

But I'm looking for an answer that is short, without any boilerplate.

Comment: Why don't you give the row a separate name? `type PersonRow = ( name :: String, age :: Int )`, and then `type Person = { | PersonRow }`

Comment: We could do it, but is there a Constraint or type class that will give rowType from Record...
something like  
```FromRecord record rowType | rowtype -> record, record -> rowtype```